# Checking one cell against two columns in two other sheets in the same workbook and showing two outputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, vlookup, xlookup

I have been trying to update a spreadsheet that i use to track whether a serial number has been issued. I want to show either "ISSUED" or "AVAILABLE" in the end column for that serial number.

i have an items list sheet that has the serial numbers and then two sheets one for Issued and one for replaced.

[image]

So the formula in column D takes the serial number in column A then checks the A columns on the two other sheets and if it listed there and if it is puts in column D "Issued" or "Available".

i have tried VLOOKUP and XLOOKUP and it returns this[image]

So sometimes it is picking up that they have been issued other times it outputs random serial numbers of dates.

any ideas on what is going wrong?

Edit: this is one of the other sheets, [image]

Comment: Please show us sample data of the two "other" sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula

```
=LET(
isIssued,ISNUMBER(MATCH([@Serial Number],tblIssued[Serial Number],0)),
isReplaced, ISNUMBER(MATCH([@Serial Number],tblReplaced[Serial Number],0)),
IF(OR(isIssued=TRUE,isReplaced=TRUE),"Issued","Available")
)
```

It checks if the serial number occurs in tblIssued, then if in tblReplaced.
If one of those is true, it returns "Issued" otherwise "Available".

I like to use LET - because it is easier to read if you come back to that formula in 6 months :-)

[image]

Comment: I have tried several times but it will not do it. i get #NAME? as an error. i also had to alter it as it would not accept the above formula.
=LET(Issued,ISNUMBER(MATCH([@[Serial Number]],tblIssued!A:A,0)),Replaced, ISNUMBER(MATCH([@[Serial Number]],tblReplaced!A:A,0)),IF(OR(istblIssued=TRUE,istblReplaced=TRUE),"Issued","Available"))

Comment: Your sheets are called "Issued" and "Replaced" --> so you have to remove the "tbl"-Part